# Hashing IP Address Ranges

Tags: memory, hash

Suppose I want to block IP addresses that fit any range among a set of ranges. So for instance, I want to block IP's that are in any of these ranges:
207.154.0.0 - 207.154.63.255,
216.27.0.0 - 216.27.95.255,
209.59.0.0 - 209.59.31.255

I think it's inefficient and unfeasible to store all the possible IP addresses in these ranges in memory. If I store all the ranges in a hash, I need to iterate through all of them and see if the IP is in any of the ranges, so that seems inefficient as well as there could probably be over 100,000 ranges.

Is there a way to translate an IP address to a key that represents a range? So that if I have the IP 207.154.1.0 and 207.154.2.0, they both map to the same key, that represents the range 207.154.0.0 - 207.154.63.255 ?

Ignoring issues/alternative solutions for blocking IPs... I'm familiar with iptable, htaccess, wildcards, regular expressions, etc. What is an efficient way to store these IP ranges in a hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remembering that every IP address (for IPv4) is a group of 4 8-bit numbers, you can simply keep the first two numbers (leftmost 16 bits). As a simple solution.

123.123.xx.yyy -> 123.123 -> the binary representation of these two numbers. That's the first number times 256 plus the second number.

```
// IP address is n1.n2.n3.n4
myHash = n1*256+n2;  // integer value between 0 and 65535
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what language you're programming in; I would suggest something similar to [inet_aton](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntoaman.html) which will convert an ascii text IP address into the 32 bit integer value.  Would probably be easier to store these as integers.

If you cannot do that, then use this pseudo code.

```
Split IP by octect.
For each octect
  convert octect from ascii to integer.
  shift bits by 4 * (octect number) and add total
aton answer in total.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hash the ip address into a number:
for ip address:

> aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd

translate it into something like:
    aaabbbcccddd

then you just need to keep a range in memory:

> aaabbbcccddd - eeefffggghhh

to check whether an ip is blocked, just hash it into number and compare to the range in memory.